# Problems with iOS Publishing & Signing

Tags: ios, iphone, publish, loader, signing

I recently created an app with a popular online tool called App Architect. It creates the code for you and then allows you to publish under your own dev account and gives a whole list of instructions. Basically though I am having a whole host of problems. It gives me what I believe to be signing code for terminal however it just never works:
[when in cd Downloads]

```
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
//Press Enter
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
//Press Enter
```

--followed by

```
codesign  -f -s "iPhone Distribution: ******** (********)”--resource-rules=./Payload/AppliqueApplication-iPhone.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements .-iPhone.app/Entitlements.entitlements ./Payload/”AppliqueApplication-iPhone.app"
```

I get all sorts of errors such as 'no identity found' I have looked in to manual code signing and when I have done it says it worked but then on application loader I run in to another load of problems such as ITMS-9000??????

Any help would be much appreciated as this is my first app and I'm getting really frustrated. :P

Comment: Please help I am  getting frustrated!

Answer (score 0):

did you solved your issue ?
Depending of your Xcode version, you might need to change codesign_allocate location ...

```
Xcode < 5.0:    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
Xcode = 5.0:    /usr/bin/codesign_allocate
Xcode > 5.0.1:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
```

So export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="the path above that match your Xcode version dedicated path"

This need to be done only once.

See: [blog.hoachuck.biz](http://blog.hoachuck.biz)
Hope this help.

O.